# How can I get notified that a new child was created under specific DIV

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<DIV id='mydiv'>
```

and want to get notified when new children appear under this DIV.
Is it possible?

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: For IE, version 11+ only supports `MutationObserver`. Otherwise poll for changes using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can!

```
$("#mydiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        alert("tree changed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch the `div` element when its content changes.

```js
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  snippet.log("Element Added");
});
ob.observe(document.getElementById("mydiv"), {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
});
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = '<p>Test</p>';
}, 100);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<DIV id='mydiv'></DIV>
```